# error : Class is referenced as a converter but it does not have any converter methods

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

here is the converter class , throwing this error: Class is referenced as a converter but it does not have any converter methods.
public final class DateConvertors{..

```
      import androidx.room.TypeConverters
      import java.util.*

       class DateConvertors {

      @TypeConverters
      fun fromDateToLong(value: Date): Long {
         return value.time
       }

     @TypeConverters
      fun fromLongToDate(value: Long): Date {
         return Date(value)
       }
      }
```

this is database class where I am using that convertor

```
     @Database(entities = [Contact::class], version = 2)
     @TypeConverters(DateConvertors::class)
   abstract class ContactDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

        abstract fun contactDao(): ContactsDAO

       companion object {

    val migration_1_2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE contact ADD COLUMN isActive INTEGER NOT NULL 
       DEFAULT(1)")
        }

    }

    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: ContactDatabase? = null

    fun getDatabase(context: Context): ContactDatabase {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    ContactDatabase::class.java,
                    "contactDB"
                )
                    .addMigrations(migration_1_2).build()
            }


            }
            return INSTANCE!!
         }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are using the wrong annotation.

The functions in `DateConverters` are annotated with [`@TypeConverters`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/TypeConverters), but you should use [`@TypeConverter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/TypeConverter) there.